# Ubuntu 22.04 on mini-ITX hangs regularly

Tags: hardware

My mini-ITX with Ubuntu 22.04 hangs regularly. There is no picture on the monitor connected via HDMI. It is also no longer accessible via SSH. The problem usually occurs a few hours after power on, at irregular intervals.

What I have already examined:

- The SMART values of the hard drive are fine so far.
- The temperature curve of the CPU is also OK so far. The picture below shows the fan speed, which is normal. In the middle of the night it stopped.

  [image: CPU Temperature]
- Here is the `auth.log`:

  ```
  Jun 20 15:15:02 simon-itx CRON[3143350]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user simon
  Jun 20 15:15:03 simon-itx CRON[3143351]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user simon
  Jun 20 15:15:03 simon-itx CRON[3143352]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user www-data
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx CRON[11610]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user simon(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
  Jun 24 14:08:19 simon-itx sshd[11992]: Server listening on 0.0.0.0 port 22.
  Jun 24 14:08:19 simon-itx sshd[11992]: Server listening on :: port 22.
  Jun 24 14:08:27 simon-itx systemd-logind[11653]: New seat seat0.
  Jun 24 14:08:27 simon-itx systemd-logind[11653]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event0 (Power Button)
  Jun 24 14:08:27 simon-itx systemd-logind[11653]: Watching system buttons on /dev/input/event2 (Logitech K400)
  Jun 24 14:08:27 simon-itx gdm-autologin]: gkr-pam: no password is available for user
  Jun 24 14:08:27 simon-itx gdm-autologin]: pam_unix(gdm-autologin:session): session opened for user simon(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
  Jun 24 14:08:27 simon-itx systemd-logind[11653]: New session 2 of user simon.
  Jun 24 14:08:27 simon-itx systemd: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user simon(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
  Jun 24 14:08:30 simon-itx gdm-autologin]: gkr-pam: gnome-keyring-daemon started properly
  Jun 24 14:08:32 simon-itx gnome-keyring-daemon[12695]: The PKCS#11 component was already initialized
  Jun 24 14:08:32 simon-itx gnome-keyring-daemon[12695]: The SSH agent was already initialized
  Jun 24 14:08:32 simon-itx gnome-keyring-daemon[12695]: The Secret Service was already initialized
  Jun 24 14:08:37 simon-itx polkitd(authority=local): Registered Authentication Agent for unix-session:2 (system bus name :1.44 [/usr/bin/gnome-shell], object path /org/freedesktop/PolicyKit1/AuthenticationAgent, locale de_DE.UTF-8)
  Jun 24 14:09:01 simon-itx CRON[18254]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user root(uid=0) by (uid=0)
  Jun 24 14:09:01 simon-itx CRON[18255]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user simon(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
  Jun 24 14:09:01 simon-itx CRON[18256]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user simon(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
  Jun 24 14:09:01 simon-itx CRON[18254]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user root
  Jun 24 14:09:01 simon-itx CRON[18255]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user simon
  Jun 24 14:09:01 simon-itx CRON[18257]: pam_unix(cron:session): session opened for user simon(uid=1000) by (uid=0)
  Jun 24 14:09:03 simon-itx CRON[18256]: pam_unix(cron:session): session closed for user simon
  ```
- And here is the `syslog`:

  ```
  Jun 20 15:15:06 simon-itx sanoid[3002246]: INFO: waiting for cache update lock held by another sanoid process.
  Jun 20 15:15:37 simon-itx sanoid[3002246]: message repeated 3 times: [ INFO: waiting for cache update lock held by another sanoid process.]
  Jun 20 15:15:37 simon-itx systemd[1]: sanoid.service: Deactivated successfully.
  Jun 20 15:15:37 simon-itx systemd[1]: Finished Snapshot ZFS filesystems.
  Jun 20 15:15:37 simon-itx systemd[1]: sanoid.service: Consumed 11min 5.519s CPU time.
  Jun 20 15:15:37 simon-itx systemd[1]: Starting Snapshot ZFS filesystems...
  Jun 20 15:15:39 simon-itx sanoid[3002246]: INFO: removing destroyed snapshots from cache.
  Jun 20 15:15:39 simon-itx systemd[1]: sanoid-prune.service: Deactivated successfully.
  Jun 20 15:15:39 simon-itx systemd[1]: Finished Prune ZFS snapshots.
  Jun 20 15:15:39 simon-itx systemd[1]: sanoid-prune.service: Consumed 29min 26.581s CPU time.
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] microcode: microcode updated early to revision 0x48, date = 2021-11-16
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] Linux version 5.19.0-43-generic (buildd@lcy02-amd64-028) (x86_64-linux-gnu-gcc (Ubuntu 11.3.0-1ubuntu1~22.04.1) 11.3.0, GNU ld (GNU Binutils for Ubuntu) 2.38) #44~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Mon May 22 13:39:36 UTC 2 (Ubuntu 5.19.0-43.44~22.04.1-generic 5.19.17)
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] Command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/BOOT/ubuntu_58zi8x@/vmlinuz-5.19.0-43-generic root=ZFS=rpool/ROOT/ubuntu_58zi8x ro quiet splash vt.handoff=1
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] KERNEL supported cpus:
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000]   Intel GenuineIntel
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000]   AMD AuthenticAMD
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000]   Hygon HygonGenuine
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000]   Centaur CentaurHauls
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000]   zhaoxin   Shanghai  
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x001: 'x87 floating point registers'
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x002: 'SSE registers'
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x008: 'MPX bounds registers'
  Jun 24 14:08:15 simon-itx kernel: [    0.000000] x86/fpu: Supporting XSAVE feature 0x010: 'MPX CSR'
  ```

What else can I check? Possibly it is the power supply, but how can I read that?

Comment: Check the file `/var/log/auth.log` after the shutdown. Look for entries at the time of the shutdown. Also look at the `/var/log/syslog` entries at the shutdown time.

Comment: @user68186: Many thanks, I had a new crash this week. There is no entry for this date, it crashed on the 21 of June: https://pastebin.com/Cp7zSbTH

Comment: and the syslog: [link](https://pastebin.com/cwHrPFfG)

Comment: @Simon2019 Please update your question and add these links.